# Error en consulta MYSQL y PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

Buenas tardes. No se porque no se realiza esta consulta en PHP y Mysql

Este es el código del formulario que enviar el contenido:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario']))
{
header('Location:auth');
exit();
}
include 'conexion.php';
$usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
//Consulta numero de mensajes
$grupo= $_GET['grupo'];
$iii="1";
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Software Benedicto XVI | Software Eclesiástico SisPasIn</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/FancyZoom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/FancyZoomHTML.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" class="init">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#seminaristas').DataTable();
                rowReorder: true
        } );
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#mensajes').DataTable();
                rowReorder: true
        } );
    </script>

<body onLoad="setupZoom()">

<div class="container">
<center><h1> <font face="Trajan Pro">Resultados</font></h1></center>
<a href="index.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> Regresar</button></a></br></br>

<form method="post" name="actualizar" id="actualizar" action="actualizar.php">
    <table id="seminaristas" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Apellidos, Nombre</th>
            <?php
              $sentencia=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'");
              While($resultado=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia)){
            ?>
                  <th><?php echo $resultado['nombre_calificacion']; ?> (<?php echo $resultado['porcentaje']; ?>%)</th>
            <?php } ?>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Apellidos, Nombre</th>
            <?php
              $sentencia=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'");
              $numero = mysqli_num_rows($sentencia);
              While($resultado=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia)){
            ?>
                  <th><?php echo $resultado['nombre_calificacion']; ?> (<?php echo $resultado['porcentaje']; ?>%)</th>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <?php //carga los nombres
            $ss=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM seminaristas JOIN grupo_estudiante WHERE grupo_estudiante.Idg='$grupo' AND grupo_estudiante.Id=seminaristas.Id ORDER BY seminaristas.apellido, seminaristas.nombre ASC");
    $ii="1";
    While($rr=mysqli_fetch_array($ss)){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $rr['apellido']; ?>, <?php echo $rr['nombre']; ?></td>

    <?php
      $sentencia2=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'");
      $i="1";
      While($resultado2=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia2)){

        $numero_cali=$resultado2['Idcal'];
      $estudiante=$rr['Id'];

        $sentencia3=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM notas WHERE calificacion='$numero_cali' AND estudiante='$estudiante' AND grupo='$grupo'");
        $resultado3=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sentencia3);
      ?>

<td><input name="nota<?php echo $i; ?>[]" data-id="<?php echo $estudiante; ?>" id="nota<?php echo $i; ?>-<?php echo $estudiante; ?>" value="<?php echo $resultado3['nota']; ?>" /> <input data-id="<?php echo $estudiante; ?>" id="porcentaje<?php echo $i; ?>-<?php echo $estudiante; ?>" style="display:none" value="<?php echo $resultado2['porcentaje']; ?>" /> <input name="idnota<?php echo $i; ?>[]" id="idnota<?php echo $i; ?>-<?php echo $estudiante; ?>" style="display:none" value="<?php echo $resultado3['Idn']; ?>" /></td>
<td hidden><input name="idn[]" id="<?php echo $iii; ?>" value="<?php echo $iii; ?>" /></td>
<td hidden><input name="grupo" id="grupo" value="<?php echo $grupo; ?>" /></td>

<?php $i++; $iii++; } ?>

<td><input name="resultado[]" id="resultado-<?php echo $estudiante; ?>" value="0" readonly /></td>
<?php $ii++; } ?>
        </tr>
</table>

</th>

<input type="submit" name="actualizar" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-info col-md-offset-9" />
</form>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input').click(function() {
$(this).select();
});


$(document).ready(function(){
$("#actualizar").find(':input').each(function() {
var elemento= this;
var dataid = $(this).data('id');

<?php
  $sentencia2=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'");
  $i="1";
  While($resultado2=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia2)){
  ?>
  var nota<?php echo $i; ?> = parseFloat($('#nota<?php echo $i; ?>-' + dataid).val());
  var porcentaje<?php echo $i; ?> = parseFloat($('#porcentaje<?php echo $i; ?>-' + dataid).val());
<?php $i++; } ?>

var resultado = <?php  $sentencia22=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'");
$i="1";
$numero = mysqli_num_rows($sentencia22);
While($resultado22=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia22)){
?>(nota<?php echo $i; ?>*porcentaje<?php echo $i; ?>/100) <?php if ($i < $numero) {  echo "+"; } else { echo ""; } ?> <?php $i++; } ?>

$('#resultado-' + dataid).val(resultado);
});
});

$('input').keyup(function() {
var dataid = $(this).data('id');

<?php
  $sentencia23=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'");
  $i="1";
  While($resultado23=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia23)){
  ?>
  var nota<?php echo $i; ?> = parseFloat($('#nota<?php echo $i; ?>-' + dataid).val());
  var porcentaje<?php echo $i; ?> = parseFloat($('#porcentaje<?php echo $i; ?>-' + dataid).val());
<?php $i++; } ?>

var resultado = <?php  $sentencia22=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'");
$i="1";
$numero = mysqli_num_rows($sentencia22);
While($resultado22=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia22)){
?>(nota<?php echo $i; ?>*porcentaje<?php echo $i; ?>/100) <?php if ($i < $numero) {  echo "+"; } else { echo ""; } ?> <?php $i++; } ?>

$('#resultado-' + dataid).val(resultado);
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Y este es el código que ejecuta la consulta.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<?php
    include 'conexion.php';
    $grupo= $_POST['grupo'];

    $i="1";
    if(isset($nota[$i]))
    {
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($_POST['idn']); $i++)
        {
            $sentencia23=mysqli_query(
                $conexion,
                "SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'"
            );
            $numero = mysqli_num_rows($sentencia23);

            $ii='1';
            $nota='nota';
            $idnota='idnota';


            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE notas SET nota = ? WHERE Idn = ?");

            while ($resultado23 = mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia23))
            {
                ${$nota.''.$ii}   = $_POST[$nota.''.$ii][$i];
                ${$idnota.''.$ii} = $_POST[$idnota.''.$ii][$i];

                //$result = $conexion->query(
                //  "UPDATE notas SET nota = \'$nota.''.$ii\' WHERE Idn = \''$idnota.''.$ii'\'"
                //);
                $stmt->bind_param(
                    'ss',
                    $_POST[$nota.''.$ii][$i],
                    $_POST[$idnota.''.$ii][$i]
                );

                $stmt->execute();
                $ii++;
            }
        }
    }

    //Comprobación de la actualización
    $res = ($resultado = $conexion->query($stmt))
        ? "Los datos han sido actualizados satisfactoriamente."
        : "Intente nuevamente, no se ha podido ejecutar la actualización."
            . $ejecucion->error;
    /*
    //Comprobación de la actualización
    if ($resultado = $conexion->query($stmt))
    {
        $res = "Los datos han sido actualizados satisfactoriamente.";
    }
    else 
    {
        $res = "Intente nuevamente, no se ha podido ejecutar la actualización." . $ejecucion->error;
    }
    */

    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo $res;
?>

</html>
```

Los errores que aparecen son:

> Notice: Undefined variable: stmt in C:\xampp\htdocs\seminario\academia\actualizar.php on line 35
>
> Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\seminario\academia\actualizar.php on line 35
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: ejecucion in C:\xampp\htdocs\seminario\academia\actualizar.php on line 38
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\seminario\academia\actualizar.php on line 38
> Intente nuevamente, no se ha podido ejecutar la actualización.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Es curioso, en una parte usas sentencias preparadas y en otra generas sentencias SQL concatenando cadenas y abriendo la puerta a ataques de inyección SQL.

Comment: Aparte, ¿has editado el error que compartes? En el código de la pregunta hay una variable no definida que te debería dar el error que muestras pero se llama `$stmp` y no `$stmt`.

Comment: me parece que el error es que el if donde definde smt jamás entra dado que no existe la variable  $nota, por lo cual $stmt no se declara y marca el error

Comment: Entonces que solución me proponen ustedes? como puedo organizarlo, es urgente?... muchas gracias

Comment: Para empezar declara el arreglo nota, fíjate en esa linea, $nota no lo declaraste en ningún lado, si quieres comprobar que es eso, cambia el if(isset($nota[$i)) por if(true), si funciona todo bien es eso que te mencono

Comment: Ya hice el cambio que me propusiste -poner if(true)- y me sigue apareciendo un error, dice: Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\seminario\academia\actualizar.php on line 19

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\seminario\academia\actualizar.php on line 19

Comment: Y cómo puedo declarar el arreglo?

Comment: El nuevo error que recibes es porque la conexión a la base de datos ha fallado. Te recomiendo que depures el código, muestres los errores (p.e. con `error_reporting(E_ALL)` y veas los valores de las variables para ver dónde puede estar el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, todo el bloque de código que realiza las consultas lo haces dentro de un bloque condicional `if(isset($nota[$i])) {...}`, cuando no veo definido el array ***$nota***, con lo que no va a entrar ¡NUNCA!, y por eso tu programa no consulta nada. Si lo tienes en el fichero 'conexion.php' o en otros de los que tire este: mala práctica, te estás trayendo una conexión y lógica en un mismo fichero (datos necesarios).

**Sobre los errores...**

El **primer 'Notice'** que se refiere a que no ésta definida $stmt, es porque para obtener el texto con el resultado usas esta variable, que se definio dentro del bloque anterior: si el programa no entra no se denine. Puede evitarse de dos formas:

*Solución 1*

Establecer un mensaje por defecto previamente al bloque condicional y mover esta parte de obtención de 'feedback' dentro del bloque condicional. Si no entra tienes el mensaje por defecto.

*Solución 2*

Declarar la variable $stmt previamente al condicional en que aparece asignandole un nulo, sino se entra al condicional obtienes el mensaje: "Intente nuevamente, no se ha podido ejecutar la actualización."

Yo optaría por la opción 1, que te da un indicio de lo que esta fallando y previene lo siguiente.

El **primer 'Warning'** lo tienes por el caso anterior: $conexion->query() no estaría recibiendo nada.

Tu **segundo 'Notice'**, debido a $ejecucion->error, también ésta claro, como el array del comienzo, no veo esta variable en ninguna parte.

El **tercer 'Notice'** viene del anterior, usas una sintaxis de objeto para intentar obtener un valor de una propiedad de un objeto, pero este no existe.

Puedes probar a adaptar lo siguiente, aunque hay muchas inconsistencias en tu código:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<?php
    include 'conexion.php';

    /**
     * Simulo contenido para la variable, vamos a suponer que se aceptan:
     * mañana y tarde como valores posibles
     *
     */
    $_POST['grupo'] = 'tarde';

    /**
     * Variable con contenido simulado
     *
     */
    $nota = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'valor' = 4
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'valor' = 8
        ],
        [
            'id' => 3,
            'valor' = 7
        ],
    ];

    //Obtener grupo
    $grupo = $_POST['grupo'];

    /**
     * Clausulas de salvaguarda
     * Permiten verificar condiciones y detienen el programa, reduciendo indentado
     *
     */
    if (! $conexion || ! is_object($conexion) || $conexion->connect_error)
    {
        die('ERR -> Hay una problema con la conexion.');
    }

    //
    //Si la ejecución llega aquí parece que tienes conexión con una BD
    //

    if ($grupo !== 'mañana' || $grupo !== 'tarde')
    {
        die('ERR -> El grupo no es válido.');
    }
    if(! isset($nota[0]))
    {
        die('ERR -> No hay notas registradas');
    }

    //
    //Si la ejecución llega aquí ya sabemos que el grupo es correcto y que
    //al menos tienes una nota en el array
    //

    $idn = count($_POST['idn']);
    if($idn<2)
    {
        die('ERR -> idn inferior a 2 -> no se pueden consultar calificaciones');
    }

    //
    //Si la ejecución llega aquí ya sabemos por lo menos la ejecución entrará
    //en el "for"
    //

    for ($i = 1; $i < $idn; $i++)
    {
        $select = "SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'";
        echo('Ejecutando consulta: ' . $select . '<br>'); //traza

        $sentencia23=mysqli_query(
            $conexion,
            $select
        );
        $numero = mysqli_num_rows($sentencia23);
        echo('Existen ' . $numero . ' calificaciones para el grupo de ' . $grupo . '.<br>');


        echo('Actualizando notas...');
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE notas SET nota = ? WHERE Idn = ?");
        $j=1;
        while ($resultado23 = mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia23))
        {
            ${'nota'.$j}   = $_POST['nota'.$j][$i];
            ${'idnota'.$j} = $_POST['idnota'.$j][$i];

            $stmt->bind_param(
                'ss',
                $_POST['nota'.$j][$i],
                $_POST['idnota'.$j][$i]
            );

            $stmt->execute();
            $j++;
        } //while -> Fin actualización notas

        //Comprobación de la actualización
        $res = ($resultado = $conexion->query($stmt))
            ? "Los datos han sido actualizados satisfactoriamente."
            : "Error durante la actualización.";

        /*
        //Comprobación de la actualización
        if ($resultado = $conexion->query($stmt))
        {
            $res = "Los datos han sido actualizados satisfactoriamente.";
        }
        else
        {
            $res = "Intente nuevamente, no se ha podido ejecutar la actualización." . $ejecucion->error;
        }
        */

        //Muestra resultado consultas
        echo $res;
    } //for

    mysqli_close($conexion);

?>

</html>
```

Comment: Orici aparece el error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in on line 50... Cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: Ese error es un **error de sintaxis**, quiere decir que algo no esta escrito de acuerdo a las normas básicas del lenguaje, por ejemplo si al final de una línea no pones punto y coma, aparece un *Parse error*. En tu caso y sin ver el código, puede que tengas dos veces seguidas punto y coma, o lo tengas después del cierre de un bloque, por ejemplo después de una llave o paréntesis de cierre. Este signo se usa como final de línea en instrucciones normales, no bloques.

Comment: En el código que editaste arriba, en las últimas líneas solo pudiste 2 punto y comas, cuando deberían ir 3 o 4. O así está correcto?

Comment: @Fredy Aristizábal Aristizábal sólo va un punto y coma al final, el anterior es un error mio, es como si fuera una sola línea, se separa en varias por legibilidad. Edite tu código añadiendo a que equivale en un comentario.

Comment: ESTOS ERRORES SIGUEN APARECIENDO, DESPUÉS DE LA CORRECCIÓN QUE LE HICISTE AL CÓDIGO:
Notice: Undefined variable: stmt in C:\xampp\htdocs\seminario\academia\actualizar.php on line 49

Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\seminario\academia\actualizar.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined variable: ejecucion in C:\xampp\htdocs\seminario\academia\actualizar.php on line 52

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\seminario\academia\actualizar.php on line 52
Intente nuevamente, no se ha podido ejecutar la actualización.

Comment: Es decir que siguen apareciendo los mismos errores del inicio. será que monto el código de la página que envía los datos a esta, además de la estructura de la base de datos o no hay necesidad ?

Comment: Orici  que puedo hacer entonces?

Comment: Orici ya puse el código del formulario que envía la información a actualizar.

Comment: He estado acomodando mi formulario al que me sugieres y el problema radica en que no está recibiendo el Array... Cómo lo puedo solucionar? Ayer puse el código de la página que enviar las notas es decir dónde está el formulario... Muchas gracias!